# Slide flickering with CSS transitions

Tags: css, slider, transform, frontend, slick.js

Have been researching possible fixes for this and just cannot figure out what's wrong.

The issue seems to only be in chrome. But it doesn't happen in Chrome Canary.

http://jsfiddle.net/de2yzzds/6/ (use arrow keys to navigate and I also need the html this way)

The slide flickers when it goes from the last slide to the first slide

I'm on a mac using Chrome Version 47.0.2526.80 (64-bit)

Using latest version of https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick

Can anyone else recreate the issue?

I've tried these solutions.

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);

-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

[image]

Comment: Using your same fiddle, I do not have this issue on the latest version of Chrome (48.0.2564.109 on a Windows PC).

Comment: Were you ever able to fix this? I'm experiencing something similar.

Answer (score -1):

probably there is another style-sheet in your website that creates this problem.