# how to remove whitespace at the bottom of glide.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, glidejs

Can anyone please help me remove whitespace at the bottom of image or slider?

Image preview:

[image: image preview]

project code link http://playcode.io/661392

I have downloaded and used css file for glide.core.min.css and glide.theme.min.css since CDN didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `font-size: 0;`
The space must be because of spaces.

Comment: thanks a lot! it really did work, no idea how the font space got involved where no fonts or its properties were used.

also can you please help me fix this issue?
https://gyazo.com/ffcd4ab0499602e43e9d4715c52346de

there is a white space flickering at the last or first item of carousel when swiped

Comment: i downloaded your code files but there was no issue here. this issue is faced by quite a number of people i guess. you get many results in google. like https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/1961 , https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/1890. maybe something like the following might work: `.slick-track,
.slick-list {
-webkit-perspective: 2000;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}`

Comment: Hmmm..! i used your code and also went through the link you mentioned but nothing seems to be working. Also did cross browser test but the problem remains. Anyways, you've been a great help. Thank you very much mate.)

Comment: ah don't mention. and i don't think you are gonna find much help in the comments now that you've accepted my answer. you should probably ask a new question bout this flickring

Comment: temporary fix without explanation: from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34215043/slide-flickering-with-css-transitions), i got this `* {
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}`. obviously don't use '*' selector. you might know which selector to use. this should work after linking your css to html which isn't currently linked

Comment: it seems the flickering bug appears on some specific window sizes. i'm afraid * {     transform: translate3d(0,0,0); } wasn't much of a help either